# Strange error in wordpress after move to another server

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

A few days ago I moved my website to another server. Everything went according to plan, but the problem appeared when the caching plugin was turned on. The problem appears regardless of the plugin, I tested on WP Rocket, WP SuperCache, WP Fastest Cache. If I start one of them, this error appears immediately, but if I turn it off after 3 or 4 minutes, the problem disappears.

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/*****/domains/********/public_html/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5.5/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Could it be different versions of php on the 2 servers?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all cache files and folders manually? Including wp-content/advanced-cache.php. Also check if there are any cache attributes stored in config.php.